# How do I pass an additional cookie when using chrome WebSockets?

Tags: authentication, cookies, google-chrome-extension, websocket

I am building a chrome extension. In it, I use this code:

```
new WebSocket("wss://api.example.com/");
```

The problem is that the website with the cookie in my browser is `WWW.example.com` so WebSockets wont pass the session cookie.

What I need is this:

```
new WebSocket("wss://api.example.com/", { "cookies": [ { "session": sessionKey } ] });
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The domain that created the cookie gets to decide whether subdomains are allowed to see the cookie or not.  Only the creator of the cookie can do anything about that.  If `www.example.com` sets the cookie on `example.com` and allows subdomains to see it, then `api.example.com` will be able to see it.  Otherwise, `api.example.com` will not be allowed to see that cookie.  That's just how browser security works.

If you know the `sessionKey` in your Javascript, you yourself can set that into an `example.com` cookie that allows subdomains and then it will be automatically sent with the webSocket request to `www.example.com`.  You don't send cookies explicitly.  You set cookies on your domain and allow access to subdomains.  Then, the cookies will get sent automatically on both Ajax calls and webSocket connect requests.

In your specific case, you can do this:

```
document.cookie = "session=" + sessionKey + ";path=/;domain=example.com;"
```